# Could not find android.jar for API Level 25

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Estou tentando apenas rodar um simples "Hello World", no Visual Studio. Criei um projeto do tipo Cross Plataform. Eu instalei o Visual Studio 2017, ao tentar rodar não abre o emulador, gerando o seguinte erro:

**Erro:** `Could not find android.jar for API Level 25. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 25 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar missing.)`

[image: Erro retornado ao tentar Ctrl+F5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aparentemente só está faltando a plataforma para a qual seu projeto foi criado, então deves instalar a versão correta. Vá em Ferramentas>> Android>>Gerenciador do SDK do Android, sem seguida selecione a opção da versão do pacote correspondente, clique em Instalar Pacote. Isto deve resolver.